# style input component in kendo-ui for angular2

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendonumerictextbox

I'm trying kendo ui for ng2. I've used the numericinput textbox but I can't find a way on how to style it, in particular I'm need to change the with 100%, how is this possible?

```
           <kendo-numerictextbox   [value]="kendonumericvalue"
                                   formControlName="kendoNumericTextControl" 
                                   [min]="-3"
                                   [max]="10"
                                   [autoCorrect]="true"
                                   style="width: 100%"> //<--not working
           </kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working in this plnkr  - http://plnkr.co/edit/TM86TiyFkDQXxXRNIVEv?p=preview

```
 <kendo-numerictextbox [value]="value"
     [min]="-3"
     [max]="10"
     [autoCorrect]="true"
     style="width: 100%"> //<--applied to the host element
 </kendo-numerictextbox>
```